# How to test website based on zip code targeting that is derived from IP address?

Tags: geolocation, ip, ip-address

We are implementing targeted content on a website based on geo-location. We are first obtaining the user's IP address and then converting it to a zip code. We then determine if that zip code is one of the zip codes in our geo-location list and then present a user with targeted content. For example, we have targeted content for specific zip codes within the city of Chicago. We first translate the IP into a zip code and then see if that zip code falls into our targeted zip code list.

Is there any way that I can test this? Not only would I have to fake my IP address, but I would have to make sure that IP address translated to a zip code that was on the list provided. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying code is determining the request's IP address from the http headers then the solution is simple, as you can use `curl` to provide any value you'd like for these headers. However, if the code obtains the ip address any other way, then you're right, you'd have to spoof your address.

Answer (score 0):

One way to test the if your application working accordingly based on geo-location is to use vpn. 
http://getfoxyproxy.org/
http://locaproxy.com/